# Is it possible to run HttpServer and WPF as a single app?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, httplistener

I have 2 apps: 1 app is a simple HttpListener Console app. It accepts the request via localhost:1234 and returns the video file as the array of bytes.
My other app is a simple WPF stand alone app, which contains the MediaElement where the source is pointing to the localhost:1234.
I'd like to have only 1 WPF app. Is it possible to include the HttpListener app inside of the WPF?
It won't work as a backgroundworker. I could run its functionality as a Thread but the MediaElement won't receive anything.
Looks like the only option is to run the HttpListener as a background process in the invisible mode.
Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# and running of HttpListener in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415763/c-sharp-and-running-of-httplistener-in-background)

Comment: No, it's useless